# Netlify Continuous Deployment Issue

Tags: vue.js, netlify

Using netlify to host spa vue application. Everything for the most part works fine and it is an awesome platform however, when I push changes that trigger a rebuild it seems to "invalidate" some of the functionality of any instance of the application currently running at that time.

For instance i have `<router-link to="/"></router-link>` which work fine until I rebuild the application.

Is there something I should be doing during the process of rebuilding or is there some type of build hook I could trigger that would refresh any current instance of the application running so that it would re validate any elements?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anything can be done except to redeploy the app on Netlify and discard the previous link that you have. I have faced such issues to and I couldn't do anything about it.